# How to reduce artifacts on curved text/vector

Tags: bezier-curves, text-object, artifacts

this is a problem I face a lot when working with branding and typography.
After importing vectors/typing, extruding and bending (simple deform or curve modifiers) it always come up with those ugly polygon artifacts:

[image]

Now, I know the cause of this is that the front faces of the text do not have the right topology nor enough polys to bend.

So, is there a good workflow to get rid of this without taking a huge load of time to retopo by hand or using the remesh modifier to an absurd high poly count?

Thanks

Comment: Please upload a blend file so that we can mess around with different possibilities before writing a guessed answer that *might* work. My first guess would be to use Remesh and Decimate modifiers.

Comment: Is the object a curve or was it converted to mesh?

Comment: Text (or curve based) objects are not meant to be curved in that direction, their inadequate topology will make their triangulated nature show. Make a mesh with proper topology before bending

Comment: @piegames this is not a problem with a specific case, its very easy to reproduce with any text or vector object

Comment: @fabriced It really doesn't matter, same results

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yeah, I'm aware of that. Maybe I was not being very clear, I am looking for a fast workflow on this matter (that doesn't require to manually retopo the text)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curve Object Deformed by Curve - Distortions (Artefacts)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160720/curve-object-deformed-by-curve-distortions-artefacts)

Answer (score 3):

I added a text, converted it to a mesh and extruded it 1 upwards. To get artifacts, I used a wave modifier. Yay, artifacts:

[image]

The artifact are because of the terrible topology Blender creates of the font. Usually, if the topology is too horrible for manual fixing, add a Remesh modifier and hope the best:

[image]

The Remesh modifier needs to be before the artifact-creating deformation. If you have to many vertices at the end, adding a Decimate modifier in Collapse mode works well.

Comment: Can you expand and/or give a .blend example? Usually with me Remesh makes most of the mesh disappear

Comment: Have you unchecked "Remove disconnected pieces"? I got this problem too but forgot to mention this option in the answer.

Comment: wow thanks I had never been able to work that modifier until your comment! Thanks so much!

Comment: Edit mode > Face > Beautify Faces worked!

Answer (score 0):

What about deleting all front and back faces (select them quickly with C shortcut), selecting the remaining edge loop and fill with F?

Alternatively select the edge loops (Alt + Click) of each letter's front edge loop, duplicate it (Shift + D), make object (P), fill (F), then get the thickness back with a Solidify modifier.

Hope this helps