# Project object on curve face

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-printing

What is the best way to project this logo on this cup without so much distortions on the and of the logo.

I've tried one tip that I saw here that used lattice and shrinkwrap modifier but the result was not so good.

The idea is to 3d print this model... I would appreciate any help to make this task easy and with good result.

[image]

[image]

this last picture is the result using the tips that I saw here.

[image]

Comment: Here's some related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107019/text-on-round-surface-mug  or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70656/how-to-reduce-artifacts-on-curved-text-vector. Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42571/better-curve-text-to-mesh-generation could be useful do deal with bad deformations.

Comment: Have the text as a flat object, then Shrinkwrap that onto the cup  and add a solidify modifier.

Comment: Thank you very much all the answers.. I've solved the problem transforming the logo into curves, got and edge loop of the cup's mesh, separated and transformed into curve..

Sorry about the duplicated question.. I've really try before the question to find the answer, but my lack of experience on blender I've could not understand correctly.. 

Used the curve modifier to set the correct location than turned back to mesh made extrusion on normals directions.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to do it was to use the knife project. All you need to do is make the words 2D with no faces, go into object mode and select the words then shift select the cup and go into edit mode. Then go into the view you are in in the first image and press knife project. The only problem with this is that it will go from the view, so you may have to do each individual letter at a time from different views so you can get it looking as nice as possible. Once you finish projecting it onto the cup you can just select the faces of the words on the cup and extrude them out. Sorry it’s such a time consuming way to do it but I couldn’t figure out anything easier. Please msg me back if you need more details. By the way I was able to successfully 3d print what I made with no errors.