# How can you warp text?

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender. I stumbled upon [this on instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BiClaIvF8C0/).  **I want to know if anyone can explain how he did this?**

I also want to bend and warp letters ( or shapes for that matter) but when I deform my meshes they just seem to break. I have been looking around a few modifiers (screw or deform) 
but I'm not sure what to use.

Comment: So the is  problem about achieving that precise animation or [correctly deforming text objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70656/how-to-reduce-artifacts-on-curved-text-vector) ?

Comment: let's say it's just making this exact animation. I want to be able to make letters turn and feel "bendable" like in this animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

- Create your X object, set its origin to its geometry.
- Give your X object a *Subsurf* modifier and a *Smooth Shading*.
- Create an Empty at its base.
- Give your X object a *Simple Deform* modifier > *Twist* mode, and choose the Empty as the *Axis Origin*.
- Create 3 keyframes through the timeline for the *Deform Angle* of the modifier, for example:
- frame 0 = 0°
- frame 30 = 120°
- frame 60 = 0°

Now your X object twists, but you must rotate it:

- In the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Transform*, rotate your X object on the Z axis, for example:
- frame 0 = 0°
- frame 60 = -360°

To do the second twist (on the X axis), just disable the first *Simple Deform* modifier with a keyframe on its visibility (eye and camera icons) after the end of the twist, create a second Empty on the right or left of the X object, rotate this new empty 90° on the Y axis, give your X object a new *Simple Deform* modifier with this second Empty as the axis, and again, play with angles, rotation and keyframes.

Also, if you want to move your X object in your scene, parent your X object and its empties to a new empty.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! i got the whole first spin to work. I'm trying to figure out how to get the backflip to work, it seems the twist function keeps twisting it along the z axis. do u have a picture where u need the empty to be located?

Comment: I haven't try the second twist but it should work exactly like the first one except you use a second Empty and other axis of rotation. You should put the second Empty on the right or on the left of the X, exactly as if you rotated you X object 90°, do you know what I mean?

Comment: fixed it! i changed the origin point of my object to it's center like it was in your foto's! now it's spinning properly, thanks!

Comment: Oh yes of course the origin is supposed to be on the object geometry  ;)  I've just edited to specify it

Comment: ok, i can't get it to work. it spins now, but when i twist it and select my second empty. who i placed where you said it twists very odd like. You think u can help me there?

Comment: oh yes because you need to rotate the second Empty 90° on the Y axis (also, don't forget to disable the visibility of the first Simple Deform modifier, i.e. camera and eye icons, with keyframes)

Comment: Thanks big ups! i would have never figured that out haha! thanks for everything it's working now.