# How do I get rid of these wrinkles in texts

Tags: text-object

Whenever I add a curve modifier to this text object, It shows these weird wrinkles in some of the letters. If anyone has a solution the solve this, that would be greatly appreciated. This is Blender version 2.79 in cycles render.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70656/how-to-reduce-artifacts-on-curved-text-vector

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39565/text-on-a-balloon/

Comment: the pology must be bad, your mesh needs more edge loops to be able to bend properly. Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

Every polygon needs to get broken down into triangles.
As your mesh has a bad topology, this is expected and would not behave differently in any other software or version.
Solution: Retopologize your mesh, at least subdivide it.